square radar chart in R
I'd like to plot a square radar chart (not a rhombus) in R. I tried to use the fmsb library, but it appears to be unable to rotate the chart.
#create data
data_t <- as.data.frame(matrix( sample( 2:20 , 4 , replace=T) , ncol=4))
colnames(data_t) <- c("math" , "english" , "biology" , "music")
data_t <- rbind(rep(20,4) , rep(0,4) , data_t)

radarchart(data_t)



I disagree. When we compare two pairs of models with different likelihoods like in this study (Fig. 1), we get the clear comparison of each pair.

Sure it's possible. With rotated labels, because otherwise it's a bit ugly. Note I had to size down the original labels using vlcex = 0.00000001
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(fmsb)
install.packages("gridGraphics")
library(gridGraphics)

#create data
data_t <- as.data.frame(matrix( sample( 2:20 , 4 , replace=T) , ncol=4))
colnames(data_t) <- c("math" , "english" , "biology" , "music")
data_t <- rbind(rep(20,4) , rep(0,4) , data_t)

# Create the radar chart
radarchart(data_t, vlcex = 0.00000001) # put vlcex = 0 and remove the customized label code to preserve the original labels

# Customizing labels
labels <- colnames(data_t)
n_labels <- length(labels)
angles <- seq(0, 2 * pi, length.out = n_labels + 1)[-1]  # Calculate angles for labels

# Add rotated labels manually
for (i in seq_along(labels)) {
  text(
    x = 1.2 * sin(angles[i]), # Positioning based on sine for x
    y = 1.2 * cos(angles[i]), # Positioning based on cosine for y
    labels[i],
    srt = 45, # Convert radians to degrees and adjust angle
    adj = 1,
    cex = 0.8
  )
}


grab_grob <- function(){
  grid.echo()
  grid.grab()
}

g <- grab_grob()
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(angle=-45))
grid.draw(g)


